# time format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

How to get desired output in MS Excel?
note that the outage duration is in mins

```
Start time  Outage Duration (in Mins)   DESIRED OUTPUT
3:12 AM                 60               4:12 AM
4:05 PM                125                6:10 PM
```

Comment: **STOP SHOUTING**

Comment: DON"T SHOUT. Your emergency is not our emergency. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: If first column (A) is stored as time, then `A2+B2/3600` will work.

Comment: I've edited your question, removing capitalization and rewording your request. This is a community, not a service where you can request deadlines, if it's really urgent for you than better to hire a consultant.

Answer (score 0):

Try the formula:

```
=A2+TIME(0,B2,0)
```

assuming `A2` is a correctly formatted `TIME` cell.